# Clojure - Incrementing numbers in a list efficiently and concurrently

Tags: multithreading, performance, data-structures, concurrency, clojure

Short version: What's the proper way to store a list of several hundred numbers in Clojure, where each number is being incremented millions of times (potentially across several threads)?

Long version: The program starts with an empty vector where each value is initialized to 0:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...]
```

It then reads a multi-million line file, line-by-line. After performing some arbitrary computation on a line, the program increments some of the values in the vector. After the first line the vector may look like:

```
[1 1 1 2 0 1 0 1 1 ...]
```

After the second line:

```
[2 2 3 2 2 1 0 2 2 ...]
```

After ~5000 lines it may look something like:

```
[5000 4998 5008 5002 4225 5098 5002 5043 ...]
```

Since Clojure's data structures are immutable simply using `assoc` to increment a value in the vector seems incredibly wasteful, because the entirety of the vector will be copied for each increment.

What is the correct way to do this kind of concurrent data aggregation without spending all my CPU time copying immutable data structures? Should I have a vector where each element is something like a ref or atom, with all threads incrementing those shared values? Or, is there some kind of thread-level data structure that can store the counts, and then the final step is to consolidate the counts from each thread?

This probably won't be I/O bound on a single thread so I'm guessing I will split line processing across several threads. There is no limit to the length of the vector (it could be several thousand elements long) but more than likely it be around 100 elements long.

Answer (score 9):

Clojure's `vector` is persistent data structure. When updating an element within vector, it doesn't copy the entire elements, and takes essentially constant time, which means O(log<sub>32</sub> n).

But it seems that you're updating almost every element within the vector each iteration. Perhaps you want to refer [Transient Data Structures](http://clojure.org/transients).

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to create the vector as vector of atoms (rather than values) and then updating the atoms in the vector concurrently.

```
(def len 1000)

(def vec-data (into [] (repeatedly len #(atom 0))))

;Create 10 future (threads) that update the vector atoms concurrently    
(doall (for [_ (range 10)]
            (future (doall (map #(swap! (vec-data %) inc) (range len) )))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following:

- Use the `core.matrix` API for vector operations.
- Use a mutable vector implementation, perhaps [vectorz-clj](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz-clj) (assuming double precision numbers is fine for you?)
- Create an accumulator vector of whatever size you want, with `(zero-vector n)`
- Each thread will do computation on a line, producing a new vector to add to the accumulator
- You then call `(add! accumulator ...)` to do a mutable addition on the accumulator vector (If you are worried about thread safety, you can use an agent or some other concurrency technique to serialise these additions)

Answer (score 2):

I wonder whether core.matrix might be useful for this purpose.  It's a bit of overkill, but would make updating easy.  If you explore this route, I'd recommend experimenting with the different implementations (ndarray, vectorz, and clatrix support mutability) to see which is fastest for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you did say Concurrently, and I missed that until after I posted.  Sorry.  Scroll down in my post to see how I would suggest doing it concurrently.

You can use java byte arrays, or long arrays in Clojure.  You just need to carefully control how you use them.

For example, here is a prime number sieve that demonstrates two things.

First it uses a byte-array, and uses aset-byte to set bytes within the array, and later aget to access those bytes.  See the first let statement where it sets [flags (byte-array size)].  You could also use (long-array size) to return a long array.  But then you should use (aset-long array index value) to set values within that long array.

Second but not directly related to your question, this uses a transient vector (a standard Clojure feature) to build up the results at the end within a loop, and then turn that vector into a persistent vector before returning the persistent vector.

```
(defn sieve1
  "Generate a vector of all prime numbers up to maxN.
   maxN must be 2 or greater."
  [maxN]

  (when (< maxN 2)
    (throw (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. (str "parameter maxN (" maxN ") must be 2 or greater."))))

  (let [size (inc maxN) ; because array is zero based
        ;nSqrt (dbmath/isqrt maxN)
        flags (byte-array size)]
    ;(println (format "maxN: %s; size: %s; nSqrt: %s" maxN size, nSqrt))

    ; Set all flags.
    (loop [i 0]
        (when (<= i maxN)
          (aset-byte flags i 1)
          (recur (inc i))))

    ; Strike out all non primes before two.
    ; (zero and one are not prime.)
    (aset-byte flags 0 0)
    (aset-byte flags 1 0)

    ; Strike out multiples of 2.
    ;(println "strike out multiples of two.")
    (loop [j 4]
      (when (<= j maxN)
        ;(println (format "aset %s 0" j))
        (aset-byte flags j 0)
        (recur (+ j 2))))

    ; Strike out multiples of primes (only odd primes are now remaining)
    ;(println "strike out multiples of primes.")
    (loop [i 3]
      (when (<= i maxN)
        (when (= 1 (aget flags i))
          ; found that i is prime.
          ;(println (format "discovered i is prime: i=%s;" i))

          ; Strike out multiples of i, starting with i^2.
          (loop [j (* i i)]
            (when (<= j maxN)
              ;(println (format "aset %s 0" j))
              (aset-byte flags j 0)
              (recur (+ j i))))
          )
        (recur (+ i 2))))

    ; Build result.
    (let [primes (transient [2])]
      (loop [i 3]
        (when (<= i maxN)
          (when (= 1 (aget flags i))
            (conj! primes i))
          (recur (+ i 2))
          ))
      (persistent! primes))
    ))
```

Why do I use a byte-array for the flags, and then a transient vector to create the resulting vector?  To make it fast!  All of the byte-array stuff and transient vector stuff happens completely within the routine, on a single thread, and does not leak out.  Try (sieve1 10000000) on ten-million to see how fast it is.

Concurrently.

What if you put a long-array within an atom.  Then use Clojure's swap! to get the concurrency.  Swap! will guarantee that only one thread at a time swaps the contents of the atom (the long-array) with a new value of the atom (even though your swap function could just return the same long-array, but after altering some of the long values within the array).  As long as all of your threads have a gentleman's agreement not to alter the long-array except by using swap! then I don't see a problem.